# Cannot Access Data Created With FactoryBot In ActiveRecord connected_to block

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord, factory-bot

I am having an issue with a test that is dependent on data created by my factory.

I noticed that I can access data created in the test and prior to this block

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :read_only_slow) do
```

I am wondering if there is way to get this block to take in to account data that is created from a factory/during my test.

Example:

```
module CustomMod
  module CustomMod2
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    class_methods do
       def klass_method
         # Here I can access instances created in my factory
        ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :read_only_slow) do
          # Here I cannot access instances created in my factory
          find_by_sql <<-SQL
            #SQL Queries
          SQL
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you create local variables in the place where you can access the instance and then access the local variable in the proc?

Comment: The method seems to connect to a different database (a read-only database). How is that database configured in your test environment? Are you allowed to write to that database?

Comment: @spickermann the test environment seems to be creating a new database as needed. `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.{instance variables}` gives me `database_test-4` prior to the block and `database_test` afterward. `read-only-slow` points to `database_test`